# Disable shortcut key for Kde(kubuntu)

Tags: shortcut-keys

I would like to know how I can disable ALL keyboard shortcuts via the terminal. I know you can disable them by going to:

system settings>keyboard>shortcuts

but I want to disable them via root file system (it should permanently disable shortcut key). anyone knows how this can be done?

Comment: all I can think of, which is tedious, is overwrite undesired shortcuts using settings keyboard custom shortcuts to make each key combo do nothing at all, or something that looks like nothing (like past a "g" to the clipboard)